# How to use xgboost in R with GPU

Tags: r, windows, gpu, xgboost

is there a possibility to use xgboost on windows 11 in r with gpu?

I've already installed cuda and tried to install xgboost with gpu support:

remotes::install_github("dmlc/xgboost", subdir = "R-package", configure.args = "--use-gpu")

This is what happens:

```
* installing *source* package 'xgboost' ...
** using staged installation
** libs
Makevars.win:19: -DXGBOOST_STRICT_R_MODE=1
Makevars.win:19: -DDMLC_LOG_BEFORE_THROW=0
Makevars.win:19: -DDMLC_ENABLE_STD_THREAD=0
Makevars.win:19: -DDMLC_DISABLE_STDIN=1
Makevars.win:19: -DDMLC_LOG_CUSTOMIZE=1
Makevars.win:19: -DDMLC_CXX11_THREAD_LOCAL=0
using C compiler: 'gcc.exe (GCC) 12.3.0'
using C++ compiler: 'G__~1.EXE (GCC) 12.3.0'
using C++17
Makevars.win:19: -DXGBOOST_STRICT_R_MODE=1
Makevars.win:19: -DDMLC_LOG_BEFORE_THROW=0
Makevars.win:19: -DDMLC_ENABLE_STD_THREAD=0
Makevars.win:19: -DDMLC_DISABLE_STDIN=1
Makevars.win:19: -DDMLC_LOG_CUSTOMIZE=1
g++  -std=gnu++17 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I../..//include -I../..//dmlc-core/include -I../..//rabit/include -I../../ -DXGBOOST_STRICT_R_MODE=1 -DDMLC_LOG_BEFORE_THROW=0 -DDMLC_ENABLE_STD_THREAD=0 -DDMLC_DISABLE_STDIN=1 -DDMLC_LOG_CUSTOMIZE=1    -I"C:/RBuildTools/4.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -fopenmp -DDMLC_CMAKE_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1 -pthread    -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c xgboost_R.cc -o xgboost_R.o
xgboost_R.cc:4:10: fatal error: dmlc/common.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <dmlc/common.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf:270: xgboost_R.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'xgboost'
```

Comment: Have you tried installing from [CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=xgboost)?